# Slug e Post/Get em uma mesma Route - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
# PÁGINA DE PRODUTO - RELACIONADA AO CARRINHO
Route::get('produtos/{slug?}', 'ProdutoController@getIndex');
Route::controller('produtos', 'ProdutoController');
```

Meu código atual é o acima e está funcionando. Eu fiz isso pelo fato de que, se eu deixar apenas a linha de baixo ele não encontra o Controller na seguinte URL com slug - *localhost/site/public/produtos/meu-slug-produto*. Então eu defini uma Route apenas para quanto tiver um slug.

Nesse Controller eu também tenho um **postPagina()**. Por isso eu fiz a Route da linha de baixo. Mas não sei se é a melhor maneira. Tem como fazer isso em apenas uma Route ?

No meu ProdutoController tem:

```
public function getIndex($slug = null)
public function postInsertProduto()
```

Comment: Use o stacksnippet apenas para reproduzir problemas com css, html e js e que possam ser executados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido.

`Route::any('produtos/{slug?}', 'ProdutoController');`

E no **ProdutoController.php** fiz:

```
public function anyIndex($slug){

}
```

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#basic-routing